# twisted.web not found when importing

Tags: python, twisted

I was trying to run the following python codes in Ubuntu server 13.0 and python 2.7

```
from twisted.python.log import err
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from stringproducer import StringProducer
class WebClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):
    def getContext(self, hostname, port):
        return ClientContextFactory.getContext(self)

def display(response):
    print "Received response"
    print response

def main():
    contextFactory = WebClientContextFactory()
    agent = Agent(reactor, contextFactory)


    d = agent.request("POST", "https://myweburl");


    d.addCallbacks(display, err)
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when i tried to run it, it gave me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named twisted.web.client
```

I had tried it in the python console and twisted.internet works, but not twisted.web. Anyone has any advice how to deal with such problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have twisted web installed?  You must have `python-twisted-web` package installed under Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-twisted-web
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have been looking for.